# How to Get n-Number of Images from torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder

Tags: pytorch

I am currently experimenting on CNN using PyTorch, and the task I want the model to accomplish is to classify images.

I understand that using `torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder` can help with loading all images from my training folder, according to each subfolders' names as the labels.

I plan on taking only n-number of images from the `ImageFolder` randomly, but as far as I know, there is no mechanism for `ImageFolder` to **load n-number** of images **randomly**, where `n` is any number ranging from 1 to all available images.

How can I do that? Thanks for any help

Comment: You could use a `DataLoader` with your `ImageFolder` dataset with `batch_size=n` and `shuffle=True`.

Comment: Doesn't using batch size still load all data?

Comment: batch_size defines how large a single sample of your dataset will be. So you could sample a single batch of size n. Then only n images will be loaded. Assuming of course that you stop after the first iteration of your dataloader.

Comment: I see, so if I need to batch the loaded data, can I still do that?

Comment: Ah maybe im misunderstanding what you want to do. If you just want to take a subset of ImageFolder of size n then you could use the `Subset` dataset and provide a list of n randomly selected indices between 0 and the length of your ImageFolder dataset.

Comment: I'll give it a try

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a subset of `ImageFolder` using PyTorch's `Subset` class. We can generate random indices using numpy or some other way if you want.

```
dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(...)
dataset_subset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, numpy.random.choice(len(dataset), n, replace=False))
```

Comment: This is fine but these two objects are different,
<torch.utils.data.dataset.Subset object at 0x000002449AA71320>
and
Dataset ImageFolder
so then when we use 
trainiter = iter(train_loader)
features, labels = next(trainiter)
gives an error 
TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
how can we modify iter and next according to imagefolder object

Comment: This is not an issue with the dataset, rather it's that you're using a `DataLoader` and the default collate function doesn't know how to collate PIL Images into a batch. The standard solution is to provide transforms to `ImageFolder` when it is created, something like `ImageFolder(..., transform=tt.Compose([tt.Resize(H,W), tt.ToTensor()]))` (assuming `import torchvision.transforms as tt`). Or, less standard, you could write a custom collate function for `DataLoader` that can deal with PIL Images. For more info see https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html.

Comment: Yes, im already using 
'train':torchvision.transforms.Compose([
            torchvision.transforms.Resize(size=image_size),
            torchvision.transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
            torchvision.transforms.RandomCrop(size=image_size),
            torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
            torchvision.transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.485, 0.456, 0.406),
                                             std=(0.229, 0.224, 0.225))
but issue is same.

Comment: You should try and understand why the transform you defined isn't getting applied to your ImageFolder. This isn't really related to this question so you should post a minimal example that reproduces this problem as a new question.